# Programming AT89S8252 with Avrdude

Tags: avrdude

I've been using the below avrdude.conf segment for an AT89S825**3** (https://www.edaboard.com/threads/avrdude-and-at89s8253-conf-file.76766/) as a starting point for an AT89S825**2**. I've struggled to find any values for the memory flash read/write and memory signature read bit patterns in the datasheet. Any input is appreciated (https://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/atmel/at89s8252_ds.pdf)

```
#------------------------------------------------------------
# AT89S8253
#------------------------------------------------------------
part
id               = "8253";
desc             = "AT89S8253";
chip_erase_delay = 20000;
pgm_enable       = "1 0 1 0  1 1 0 0    0 1 0 1  0 0 1 1",
                   "x x x x  x x x x    x x x x  x x x x";

chip_erase       = "1 0 1 0  1 1 0 0    1 0 0 x  x x x x",
                   "x x x x  x x x x    x x x x  x x x x";

timeout     = 200;
stabdelay       = 100;
cmdexedelay     = 25;
synchloops      = 32;
bytedelay       = 0;
pollindex       = 3;
pollvalue       = 0x53;
predelay        = 1;
postdelay       = 1;
pollmethod      = 0;

memory "flash"
    size            = 12288;
    paged           = no;
    min_write_delay = 4000;
    max_write_delay = 9000;
    readback_p1     = 0xff;
    readback_p2     = 0xff;
    read            = "  0   0   1   0    0   0   0   0",
                      "  x   x a13 a12  a11 a10  a9  a8",
                      " a7  a6  a5  a4   a3  a2  a1  a0",
                      "  o   o   o   o    o   o   o   o";

    write           = "  0   1   0   0    0   0   0   0",
                      "  x   x a13 a12  a11 a10  a9  a8",
                      " a7  a6  a5  a4   a3  a2  a1  a0",
                      "  i   i   i   i    i   i   i   i";
mode        = 0x21;
delay       = 12;
  ;

memory "signature"
    size            = 2;
    readback_p1     = 0x1E;
    readback_p2     = 0x73;
    read            = "0  0  1  0   1  0  0  0   x  x  x  x   x  x  x  x",
                      "x  x  1  1   0  0  0 a0   o  o  o  o   o  o  o  o";
  ;
  ;
```

Below is what I've got so far (https://www.diffchecker.com/uXX0M3Fb)

```
#------------------------------------------------------------
# AT89S8252
#------------------------------------------------------------
part
id               = "8252";
desc             = "AT89S8252";
chip_erase_delay = 20000;
pgm_enable       = "1 0 1 0  1 1 0 0    0 1 0 1  0 0 1 1",
                   "x x x x  x x x x";

chip_erase       = "1 0 1 0  1 1 0 0    x x x x  x 1 0 0",
                   "x x x x  x x x x";

timeout     = 200;
stabdelay       = 100;
cmdexedelay     = 25;
synchloops      = 32;
bytedelay       = 0;
pollindex       = 3;
pollvalue       = 0x53;
predelay        = 1;
postdelay       = 1;
pollmethod      = 0;

memory "flash"
    size            = 8192;
    paged           = no;
    min_write_delay = 4000;
    max_write_delay = 9000;
    readback_p1     = 0xff;
    readback_p2     = 0xff;
    read            = "  0   0   1   0    0   0   0   0",
                      "  x   x a13 a12  a11 a10  a9  a8",
                      " a7  a6  a5  a4   a3  a2  a1  a0",
                      "  o   o   o   o    o   o   o   o";

    write           = "  0   1   0   0    0   0   0   0",
                      "  x   x a13 a12  a11 a10  a9  a8",
                      " a7  a6  a5  a4   a3  a2  a1  a0",
                      "  i   i   i   i    i   i   i   i";
mode        = 0x21;
delay       = 12;
  ;

memory "signature"
    size            = 2;
    readback_p1     = 0x1E;
    readback_p2     = 0x72;
    read            = "0  0  1  0   1  0  0  0   x  x  x  x   x  x  x  x",
                      "x  x  1  1   0  0  0 a0   o  o  o  o   o  o  o  o";
  ;
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

the attached file in this link https://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/2109556#comment-2109556
includes a AT89S8252 template, as well as a firmware update that auto-polarity senses RST of AT89S parts.